# [Error: ExpoAppAuth.Get Auth: JSON deserialization error]

Tags: react-native, expo, appauth

Getting an error using AppAuth from 'expo-app-auth';

When i try to authi get the following error: 
[Error: ExpoAppAuth.Get Auth: JSON deserialization error]

```
const config =  {   

  serviceConfiguration: {

  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/authorize',

  tokenEndpoint: 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token',
  },

  clientId: 'cilentid',

  clientSecret: 'cilentsecret',

  scopes: ['read_presence']

}
```

Is it something with the config?

Comment: What function did you perform?

Comment: async function signInAsync() {
  const authState = await AppAuth.authAsync(config)
  .catch((error, state) => console.log(error));

  return authState;

}

Comment: It works on ios btw.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is not valid.

This is related to the issue at https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/5311 - there is an error in a ternary operator in expo-app-auth which will get rolled into an upcoming release. In the meantime, you must specify a dummy value for registrationEndpoint in your service configuration object.

```js
const config =  {   

  issuer: 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token',

  clientId: 'cilentid',

  clientSecret: 'cilentsecret',

  scopes: ['read_presence'],

  serviceConfiguration: {
        registrationEndpoint: 'https://example.com'
      }

}
```

If this is not used, you can try another method.

You try `npm install react-native-app-auth --save` And follow the installation instructions according to [the model at this link.](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)

Before that, you have to eject the Expo. run `expo eject`

### Example

```js
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token',
  clientId: 'cilentid',
  redirectUrl: 'https://api.netatmo.com/',
  scopes: ['read_presence'],
  clientSecret: 'cilentsecret'
};

const result = await authorize(config);
```

Comment: I tried that it gives me "[Error: You must provide either an `issuer` or both `authorizationEndpoint` and `tokenEndpoint`]"

Comment: How about to be used as 'issuer'?

Comment: That's not true It refers to an end point as a message of error.

Comment: issuer: URL using the https scheme with no query or fragment component that the OP asserts as its Issuer Identifier

Comment: and this on ios [Error: ERR_APP_AUTH: Non-200 HTTP response (404) fetching discovery document 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]

Comment: I have issues in url token added. And know if you read my answer, but it's fake data. Network problem solving network

Comment: [Error: An exception was thrown while calling `ExpoAppAuth.executeAsync` with arguments `(
  {
  clientId = ;
  clientSecret = ;
  issuer = "https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token";
  redirectUrl = "host.exp.exponent:/oauthredirect";
  scopes =         (
      "read_presence"
  );
  serviceConfiguration =         {
      registrationEndpoint = "https://example.com";
  };
}
)`: *** +[NSURLComponents initWithURL:resolvingAgainstBaseURL:]: nil URLString parameter]

Comment: please refer https://forums.expo.io/t/error-expoappauth-get-auth-network-error/27389/7

Comment: I think this problem is still unresolved. We have no choice but to wait for a new version of this problem to be released.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Once the 'registrationEndPoint' was added we no get the urlString error. Seems like there's no fix for this?

Comment: What other methods for oauth2 is there?

Comment: I don't wanna eject.

Comment: @JonasBro how did you solve the fetching discovering document error for your app ?

Comment: @JonasBro as above, how did you resolve the `fetching discovery document` error? @ali-raza were you able to find solution to that error?